# breaking up input from a file c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a file that contains employee information on each line (id, department, salary, and name). Here is an example line:

```
45678 25 86400 Doe, John A.
```

Right now I am reading in each word using fstream, which works until I get to the name part. My question is what is the easiest way to capture that name as a whole?

```
Data >> Word;
while(Data.good())
{
    //blah blah storing them into a node
    Data >> Word;
}
```

Comment: Argh! No! That's not how to read from an iostream in a loop!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, better suggestion?

Comment: @shep: `while(Data >> Word) { /* Do Stuff */}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to define a `struct` to hold the data for an employee, the define an overload of `operator>>` to read one of those records from your file:

```
struct employee { 
    int id;
    int department;
    double salary;
    std::string name;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, employee &e) { 
       is >> e.id >> e.department >> e.salary;
       return std::getline(is, e.name);
    }
};

int main() { 
    std::ifstream infile("employees.txt");

    std::vector<employee> employees((std::istream_iterator<employee>(infile)),
                                     std::istream_iterator<employee>());

    // Now all the data is in the employees vector.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::ifstream in("input");
  std::string s;
  struct Record { int id, dept, sal; std::string name; };
  Record r;
  in >> r.id >> r.dept >> r.sal;
  in.ignore(256, ' ');
  getline(in, r.name);
  std::cout << r.name << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `getline` is nice! (but `ignore` is not as nice..)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a record and define the input operator

```
class Employee
{
    int id;
    int department;
    int salary;
    std::string name;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, Employee& dst)
    {
        str >> dst.id >> dst.department >> dst.salary;
        std::getline(str, dst.name); // Read to the end of line
        return str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Employee  e;
    while(std::cin >> e)
    {
         // Word with employee
    }
}
```